# The derivative of the inverse square root of a Gram matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Let us assume that I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and I computed the Gram matrix $G = A^{T} A$. I would like to take the derivative of $G^{-1/2}$ with respect to $A$. I have seen some approaches utilizing eigenvalue decomposition and trying to obtain the derivative of the inverse square root from the derivative of the inverse of the Gram matrix. However, I cannot totally understand them. I would appreciate your help to solve the problem. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\M{{\rm Mat}}\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$Given
the matrix $A$, define the symmetric matrices
$$\eqalign{
G &= A^TA, \qquad F^2 = G^{-1} \quad\implies\quad F = G^{-1/2} \\
}$$
then calculate their differentials, [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products), and solve for the desired gradient.
$$\eqalign{
&dG = A^TdA + dA^TA \\
&dg = \v(dG) = \Big((I\otimes A^T) + (A^T\otimes I)K\Big)da \\
&F\,dF+dF\,F = -G^{-1}dG\,G^{-1} \\
&\big((I\otimes F)+(F\otimes I)\big)df = -\big(G^{-1}\otimes G^{-1}\big)dg \\
&\big(F\oplus F\big)df = -\big(G^{-1}\otimes G^{-1}\big)dg \\
&df = -\big(F\oplus F\big)^{-1}\big(G^{-1}\otimes G^{-1}\big)dg \\
&df = -\big(F\oplus F\big)^{-1}\big(G^{-1}\otimes G^{-1}\big)
\Big((I\otimes A^T) + (A^T\otimes I)K\Big)da \\
&df = B\,da \quad\implies\quad B = \p{f}{a} \\\\
}$$

---

If you're content with a vectorized result then you can stop here.

If you require the full matrix-by-matrix gradient, then read on.

A pair of *zero-one* third-order tensors
$$\eqalign{
{\vec\nu}_{\ell jk} &= \begin{cases}
1\quad{\rm if}\;\;\ell=j+km-m \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
{\vec\mu}_{jk\ell} &= \; {\vec\nu}_{\ell jk} \\
{\tt1}\le&j\le m,\quad {\tt1}\le k\le n \\
}$$
can be used to convert a variable between
its vector $(\vec\nu)$ and matrix $(\vec\mu)$ forms
$$\eqalign{
a &= \vec\nu:A \quad&\iff\quad A=\vec\mu\cdot a \\
}$$
and they allow the above result to be converted
from a vector-by-vector (aka matrix) gradient
into a matrix-by-matrix (aka fourth-order tensor) gradient
$$\eqalign{
df &= B\cdot da \\
\vec\mu\cdot df &= \vec\mu\cdot B\cdot (\vec\nu:dA) \\
dF &= \big(\vec\mu\cdot B\cdot\vec\nu\big):dA \\
\p{F}{A} &= \vec\mu\cdot B\cdot\vec\nu \\
}$$
or in component notation
$$\eqalign{
\p{F_{jk}}{A_{pq}}
 &= \sum_{\varepsilon=1}^{n^2}\sum_{\ell=1}^{mn} {\vec\mu}_{jk\varepsilon} B_{\varepsilon\ell} {\vec\nu}_{\ell pq} \\\\
}$$

---

In the preceeding, $\oplus$ denotes the Kronecker sum, $K$ denotes the
[Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix#2)
associated with Kronecker products, and a colon denotes the double-dot
(aka trace or Frobenius) product
$$\eqalign{
A:Z &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} Z_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(AZ^T) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped.